# DRY up code that only differs in const

Tags: c++, constants, dry

Is there a way to DRY this up (without macros)?

```
void clear_tp_vec(vector<const Tk*>& tps){
    for(auto it=tps.begin();it!=tps.end();++it ){
        const ValT* vp=dynamic_cast<const ValT*>(*it);
        if(vp!=NULL) 
            delete vp;
    }
    tps.clear();
};

void clear_tp_vec(vector<Tk*>& tps){
    for(auto it=tps.begin();it!=tps.end();++it ){
        ValT* vp=dynamic_cast<ValT*>(*it);
        if(vp!=NULL) 
            delete vp;
    }
    tps.clear();
};
```

The only thing the second overload differs in is the **const** qualifier (the lack thereof). Commenting out either version breaks my code.

Comment: Define it as a template.

Comment: The for loop could be shorter: for(auto it=tps.begin();it!=tps.end();++it )
        delete dynamic_cast<const ValT*>(*it);

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I could delete nullptr's.

Comment: Defining it as a template does the job, though it is somewhat more general than necessary. Maybe I'll look into enable_if to see if I can restrict it to these two types. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you dynamic-casting before deletion?

Comment: @Johnsyweb It's for cleaning up vectors of base-class pointers to objects representing tokens in a math expression (values, operators, functions). Value tokens are allocated dynamically, while  function and op token pointers are made to point to class-wide constant storage and so cannot be deleted (d-casting them to a value token will give a nullptr thereby preventing unwanted deletion).

Comment: Aha. That information would be really useful in the question. Perhaps a better approach would be to store these pointers in a separate container for cleanup (or to use a reference-counted smart pointer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments (@cup's "make it a template", @user1764961's "get rid of the" NULL test) have led me to the following, very obvious, modified version:

```
 template<typename T>
 void clear_tp_vec(vector<T>& tps) {
      for(auto it=tps.begin(); it!=tps.end(); ++it )
           delete dynamic_cast<const ValT*>(*it);
      tps.clear();
 }
```

Comment: If you guys want the default-answer points, may your nickname be @cup or @user1764961 and your answer be this or equivalent, or better yet, be anyone and improve this so that it only instantiates for `Tk*` `const Tk*`. No boost please (only C++ (C++11 is OK, as the code obviously uses it already).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following template function:

```
template < typename T >
void clear_tp_vec( vector< T* >& tps )
{
    typedef typename conditional< is_const< T >::value, const ValT, ValT >::type OUT;
    for ( auto it = tps.begin(); it != tps.end(); ++it )
    {
        OUT* vp = dynamic_cast< OUT* >( *it );
        if ( vp != NULL )
            delete vp;
    }
    tps.clear();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call delete on null values so test is not needed.
Also, you should use standard algorithms on iterators, not iterate yourself.

You can use Boost.Lambda to write something very generic here using placeholders:

```
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp> 
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp> 
...
using namespace boost::lambda;
std::for_each(tps.begin(), tps.end(), bind(std::ptr_fun(operator delete), *_1));
```